# Borland c++: Error while assigning OnChange to another function?

Tags: c++, function, onchange, c++builder, vcl

I'm tring to assign OnChange function to another function like:

```
XComp->OnChange = SycnroChange(prgManVoltageSet_SB->Address);
```

but compiler gives that error: "Not allowed type."

What should I do? Cant i assign like this?

Comment: What is SychroChange?

Comment: it s just a function getting int

Comment: `SycnroChange` returns an `int`? And what type is `XComp->OnChange` ? A function pointer?

Comment: XComp is spinedit and SycnroChange is void i mean returns nothing. i just want that when XComp changes, SycnroChange must be triggered.

Comment: Well, what you're doing now is call `SycnroChange` with `prgManVoltageSet_SB->Address` as an argument, and then trying to assign the result of that call to `XComp->OnChange`.

Comment: i assign it at the form creation step. and function is this:

void __fastcall TGenerator::SycnroChange(int add) {
    if(modemokey && !readed) {
        TLabelEdit *tEdit =  (TLabelEdit*)Sender;
        String n = tEdit->Name;
        Screen->Cursor = crHourGlass;
        tEdit->Enabled = false;
        param_data[tEdit->Address] = tEdit->Position;
        Write(tEdit->Address,param_data[tEdit->Address]);
        Screen->Cursor = crDefault;
        tEdit->Enabled = true;
    }
}

Comment: is there a way to assign any event like OnChange to another function with values (int abc)? No way?

Comment: Not directly, no.  `OnChange` requires a pointer to a method that has no parameters and no return value.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you can make assignments like that in the form ->onChange = xyz ; where xyz is another function (or member function) with proper signature. You can't bind arguments and things like that.

So you should change SynchroChange signature first (most event handlers require just a generic TObject *Sender) and then inside that function look for the prgManVoltageSet (unless can be casted from the parameter 'Sender', but I have not enough context for this)

Comment: i tried XComp->OnChange = SycnroChange; like this and SycnroChange(TObject *Sender). But Sender is coming NULL :(

Comment: And do you have access to prgManVoltageSet_SB? If so you do not need to cast Sender.

Comment: In this case I would advice looking into the docs of OnChange to see what it expects/requires.

Comment: `XComp->OnChange = SycnroChange;` is correct, but then `SycnroChange` must be changed to this declaration in your class: `void __fastcall SycnroChange(TObject *Sender)`. `Sender` should never be NULL, as every component (including `TCSpinEdit`) passes its `this` pointer as the `Sender` value, that is the whole purpose of that parameter.  This allows you to assign the same method to multiple events and know which component is triggering each event.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said, I have knew your intention is that you wanted to execute `SycnroChange(prgManVoltageSet_SB->Address)` when `XComp` changed.
So I think you can use a callback function with `boost::signal2::signal` and `boost::bind`, such as `boost::bind(&SycnroChange, this, _1)`.
When `XComp` changed, you could call the `callback(prgManVoltageSet_SB->Address)` to trigger and get an int.I hope these can help you.

Comment: This is the right idea, but the wrong implementation, as you cannot use bound functions for VCL event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `SycnroChange()` and assigning its return value to `OnChange`. The `OnChange` event expects a pointer to an object method that conforms to the signature of `TNotifyEvent`:

```
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TNotifyEvent)(System::TObject* Sender);
```

`SycnroChange()` has a return value of `void` instead.  Thus the error.

For what you are attempting, you will have to use a separate event handler method that internally calls `SycnroChange()`:

```
__fastcall TGenerator::TGenerator(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    ...
    // FYI, you can assign this at design-time instead of in code...
    XComp->OnChange = &XComChanged;
    ...
}

void __fastcall TGenerator::XComChanged(TObject *Sender)
{
    SycnroChange(prgManVoltageSet_SB->Address);
}
```